# Create a new environment with the same numbering as \newtheorem

Tags: sectioning, numbering, environments, theorems

The setup

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
 \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
 \theoremstyle{plain}
 \newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
 \newcounter{nremarkctr}
 \newcommand*{\nremarkname}{Remark \textnormal{\thenremarkctr}}
 \newenvironment{nremark}[1][\nremarkname]
 {\refstepcounter{nremarkctr}
 \begin{proof}[#1]\renewcommand*{\qedsymbol}{\(\diamond\)}}
 {\end{proof}}
 \numberwithin{nremarkctr}{section}
```

creates in Section 3 the following numbering:

> Definition 3.1
>
> Theorem 3.2
>
> Theorem 3.3
>
> Definition 3.4
>
> Remark 3.1

but I want

> Definition 3.1
>
> Theorem 3.2
>
> Theorem 3.3
>
> Definition 3.4
>
> Remark 3.5

I know that the reason for this is that I used `\numberwithin{nremarkctr}{section}`, but rather need something like `\numberwithin{nremarkctr}{definition}`, which is motivated from `\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}`. But this does not work. How can I get the desired numbering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to play with `\counterwithin` but use the correct counter (`definition`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newcommand*{\nremarkname}{Remark \textnormal{\thedefinition}}
\newenvironment{nremark}[1][\nremarkname]
  {%
    \refstepcounter{definition}%
    \begin{proof}[#1]\renewcommand*{\qedsymbol}{\(\diamond\)}%
  }
  {\end{proof}}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\begin{definition}
  foo
\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}
  foo
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
  foo
\end{theorem}
\begin{definition}
  foo
\end{definition}
\begin{nremark}
  foo
\end{nremark}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Don't abuse `proof`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{innernremark}[definition]{Remark}
\newenvironment{nremark}
  {\par\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\diamond$}\innernremark}
  {\popQED\endinnernremark}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\begin{definition}
  foo
\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}
  foo
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
  foo
\end{theorem}
\begin{definition}
  foo
\end{definition}
\begin{nremark}
  foo
\end{nremark}
\end{document}
```

[image]